# How to completely hide the jqgrid when is loading?

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I'm having a problem with my jqgrid. When I load my table and there is a lot of data get from the database, the loading process takes a few seconds (normal). Problem is that in that time I can see the column headers, no rows, and all the jqgrid without styles applied.

[image: This is what I see for a few seconds...]
And when the data is loaded the jqgrid change magically to my desired style.
I've added a loading image to the class ".ui-jqgrid .loading" and this image appears rotating in that time but I can still see the column headers fadded behind.

Is there any way to hide completely the column headers and footer during that time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you could add a code example, i might be able to help you.

But i think you can do the following. You can add a hidden class to the table and if the data is loaded, remove the hidden class with jQuery.

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="jqgrid" class="hidden"><!-- content --></table>
```

and in jQuery

```
 $(function () {
     $('#jqgrid').removeClass('hidden');
 });
```